# Java8 lambda nested null check

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Currently I am using `Optional` value in following format:
Is there a way to reduce code further ?

```
final Optional<List<ServiceAttributeValue>> attributeValueList = Optional.<Product> of(product)
         .map(Product::getServiceAttributes)
         .map(ServiceAttributeMap::getMap)
         .map((v) -> (ServiceAttribute) v.get(attributeV.getAttributeString()))
         .map((c) -> (List<ServiceAttributeValue>) c.getValueList());

if (!attributeValueList.isPresent()) {
    return null;
}

final Optional<ServiceAttributeValue> value = attributeValueList.get().stream()
         .filter((attribute) -> StringUtils.equals(attribute.getFoo(), attributeV.getBar()))
         .findFirst();

if (value.isPresent()) {
     return value.get().bar();
}

return null;
```

Comment: I suggest to add a new method to `Product`: `Stream< ServiceAttributeValue> serviceAttributeValues(String attribute)` or `ServiceAttribute serviceAttribute(String attribute)` if that's used more frequently. Anyway, I wonder which of these values can actually be `null`. Obviously not `product`, nor the return value of `ServiceAttributeMap::getMap`. Maybe not even `Product::getServiceAttributes` and definitely not `c.getValueList()`. Which would leave us only with `v.get` and a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, you should avoid return `null`, if you're already using `Optional`. Instead, an empty `Optional` should indicate, that the element is missing.

`Optional::map` will only map the value, if it is present.
So instead of checking, if the value `isPresent` and then retrunging `null`,
you can simplify this to

```
attributeValueList.flatMap(values -> values.stream().filter((attribute) -> StringUtils.equals(attribute.getFoo(), attributeV.getBar()).findFirst())
...
```

You can also apply this to the second `isPresent` check, when you change it to

```
return value.map(x -> x.bar());
```

All together could look like this (not tested, since I don't know the classes):

```
return Optional.<Product>of(product)
        .map(Product::getServiceAttributes)
        .map(ServiceAttributeMap::getMap)
        .map((v) -> (ServiceAttribute) v.get(attributeV.getAttributeString()))
        .map(c::getValueList)
        .flatMap(values -> values
            .stream()
            .filter((attribute) -> StringUtils.equals(attribute.getFoo(), attributeV.getBar()))
            .findFirst())
        .map(x -> x.bar());
```

The positive effect of this is, that your function returns an empty `Optional`, when one of the steps did not return anything. All other steps are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, given syntax doesn't compile for me for line  filter and findFirst

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you used a collection inside it. I changed the code, maybe you can check itr again.